# How to parse through a .dat file and get patterns such as timestamps and file size of a .jar file declared inside

Tags: regex, shell, parsing, unix

How to parse through a .dat file and get patterns such as timestamps and file size of a .jar file declared inside?

Inside the dat file there are a lot of texts but I am trying to find line such as this:

12343 2015-04-24 16:12:37 sample.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -nle "print $1 if /(\d+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+.*?\.jar)/" input.dat
```

or almost the same using grep:

```
grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+.*?.jar" input.dat
```

grep uses POSIX regex syntax which is heavier so I'd stick with the perl variant whenever possible.

Update:

To get the data for a particular file name replace the "just something up to the closest .jar" pattern (`.*?.jar`) with the desired file name:

```
perl -nle "print $1 if /(\d+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+sample.jar)/" input.dat
```

or

```
grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+sample.jar" input.dat
```

Comment: How about if I only want the size and timestamp given the jar filename?

Comment: Updated the reply with more narrow filters

Comment: It's not returning anything. perl -nle "print $1 if /(\d+\s+\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+.*?\sample.jar)/" input.dat did return values

Comment: It is not returning in grep -Eo "[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+sample.jar" input.dat

Comment: Well, this needs to be adjusted to your data file since it works perfectly wellfor my test data. What does the first, more generic, pair of commands return in your case?

Comment: It returns all jar files inisde .dat file. It's ok now mate , I just made some workaround in grep. Thanks for the help!